# Nginx proxy_pass connection timeout with very basic config

Tags: nginx, timeout, proxypass

First off, I'm pretty new to nginx. I'm trying to get a prerender going for our site, which involves doing a rewrite & proxy_pass, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what's making it fail.

This config I'm using below is only for troubleshooting, but it still gives me connection timeouts after 60 seconds. I can point it at any IP or host and it'll fail. Using wget to retrieve pages at any IP or host retrieves pages just fine, such as http://www.google.com, or the server I'm trying to hit, http://service.prerender.io, so it's something to do with how nginx is doing proxy_pass.

The server is at 10.3.3.91 internally. Oddly, I can point the proxy_pass at 10.3.3.92 (another nginx server) and retrieve pages.

I'm at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
worker_processes 4;

worker_rlimit_nofile 65000;


events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}

http {

        # Logging Settings
        access_log /var/log/nginx/test1-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/test1-error.log;

  server {
    listen 80;

#    location / {
#        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
#    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token OUR_TOKEN;
        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
            set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://$prerender;
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of what I see in the error log:

```
2016/08/26 10:03:12 [error] 3635#0: *249 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.103.11.151, server: , request: "GET /something.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://54.225.208.171:80/http://10.3.3.91/something.php", host: "10.3.3.91"
```

Comment: Please describe what the prerender service does and how one utilizes it, if it is not just a normal back end.

Comment: The prerender service basically renders JS based pages into crawlable pages by many search engines. I've stripped out nearly all of their config to force every request through the pre-render.

Comment: Just to reiterate, I can do curl & wgets of any site with no issue. I have no includes in my config saying which sites are allowed or not, and nothing like that in my config. Is there anything else I'm missing that could tell ngnix which sites are allowed, and which aren't? Some sort of white/blacklist I'm missing?

Comment: If service.prerender.io behaves like a normal back end- it takes what would be a client side route and returns html- it seems like you should just put "proxy_pass http://service.prerender.io/;" below the proxy_set_header line, add a "proxy_set_header Host $host;" and then get rid of the resolver, set, and rewrite lines. The resolver line should be unnecessary- if it is adding value, there are bigger problems. The set line is unnecessary. The rewrite line is broken, but should be unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried eliminating the rewrite & resolver, and specifying the proxy pass directly, and I still get a connection time out.

Comment: Want to post the nginx log again? The message should be different.

Comment: I changed a few things. I changed the location / to /test, and I changed the destination to my local machine running its own prerender (10.3.3.91:3000), I get the same result `2016/08/29 09:48:19 [error] 9315#0: *95 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.103.11.151, server: , request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.103.11.151:3000/test", host: "10.3.3.91"`

Comment: Additionally, proxy_pass to http://www.google.com fails, but curl to it succeeds:

Comment: The log suggests that nginx thinks your machine is 10.103.11.151- this is both client and upstream- and nginx itself is running on 10.3.3.91. Is that possible? It would not be surprising if your machine could connect to nginx running on a server but nginx could not connect back to your machine. One way traffic rules are common. What would be needed to enable nginx to talk to a prerender server is either to run prerender on the nginx host, or talk to a network team about whitelisting the public prerender ip from the nginx network.

Answer (score 0):

Our network team made a web proxy exception for a few different domains, purple.com for example to test, I changed the proxy_pass to hit purple.com, and it works. As far as I can tell, proxy_pass was having a problem understanding the responses from our web proxy, where CLI commands such as wget & curl were not.

Comment: Even it's an old question, you can change the timeout. This might be to solve for testing, but not to fix this `proxy_connect_timeout 600; proxy_send_timeout 600; proxy_read_timeout 600; send_timeout 600;` in fact, 600 might be a good thing, in case of testing but for a productive system totally overpowered